# Import LaTeX from Wikipedia to Mathematica

Tags: html

Here is one a problem I land on from time to time.

Sometimes while researching, I want to pull a formula presented in a Wikipedia page and import it into Mathematica.

I've heard that Wikipedia uses LaTeX but how could I get that out of the final HTML markdown and into MM?

Is there a 'translator' somewhere?

Comment: Are you talking about MathML, JSMath, MathJax, or something else? Do you have an example? What have you tried?

Comment: As far as I can see Wikipedia generates an image and puts the LaTex code in the alt attribute. Where did you see them using <Math>? To me, this question is the same a converting LaTex formulas to *Mathematica* code.

Comment: @Pickett - When you edit a Wikipage with a formula in it, you can see the formula encapsulated in <math> tags.

Comment: @Jens - I had tried to do this quite sometime ago, but it didn't quite work due to some differences in the formatting between Wikipedia and MM. I cannot remember know what I did, but it was an older version of MM. I was wondering if there was something new and improved in V9x.

Comment: Just like Stackexchange websites use Markdown to format posts Wikipedia uses its system, and <math> is part of that system. <math> in this case has nothing to do with HTML. I think you should rewrite your question and ask instead how you can turn LaTex into *Mathematica* code, because this is really what you ask.